My flask application requires to be restarted to display new database records
I am working on a application. I am using HTML, CSS, Jquery, Flask, MySQL-Python-Connector, Flask-Session. The data will be pushed into the database by some other application and this interface will only be used to view the records in the database. I need to restart the flask application every time a new record is pushed into the database else the old records keep showing up even after infinite page refreshes.
I thought it may be I was using the debug mode while running the application but that does not resolved the issue:
app.run(port=5000)

It's impossible to know for sure without a [mre], but it sounds as if connection or transaction management is not being handled correctly.

I resolved this issue by adding db.commit() line after fetching the results.
The following was my previous code:
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, tuple(params))
results = cursor.fetchall()

The following is my new code:
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, tuple(params))
results = cursor.fetchall()
db.commit()


In more complex applications, it is not recommended to commit after every database query. You should consider my solution instead.

You should avoid using pure MySQL connector for handling requests. For Flask it is recommended to use Flask-SQLAlchemy due to possibilities of handling app context.
Try installing needed libraries by running:
pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
pip install mysqlclient

Tutorial about Flask-SQLAlchemy: Link to YouTube.
